# Error in karma testing:oc.lazyLoad

Tags: karma-runner, oclazyload

I am getting this error in Karma while testing

> Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module *** due to:
>   Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module oc.lazyLoad due to:
>   No module found during bootstrap, unable to init ocLazyLoad

This is my angular init:

```js
angular.module('*** ', [
      'ui.router',
      'ui.bootstrap',
      'oc.lazyLoad',
      'ngResource',
      'pascalprecht.translate',
  ])
```

Can you help me to resolve this please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've resolved this problem by installing ocLazyLoad another time and add its path to karma.comfig.js files

Comment: can  you please explain how to do this?

Comment: You can do this with bower .. `bower install oclazyload` .. you can find more information in this link : [install oclazyload](https://oclazyload.readme.io/docs)