# Karma tests error "unable to init ocLazyLoad"

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, karma-runner, oclazyload

From the quickstart [sb-admin-angular](https://github.com/start-angular/sb-admin-angular), I am trying to run the tests, but I get the error `unable to init ocLazyLoad`. (This is a Windows7 machine.)

The command I use to run the tests is:

```
$ grunt test --force
```

I understand from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31939956/error-in-karma-testingoc-lazyload) that I must make sure that the path to the ocLazyLoad script is added in `karma.conf.js`.

```
files: [
  'bower_components/angular/angular.js',
  'bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
  ...
  'bower_components/oclazyload/dist/ocLazyLoad.min.js',
  'app/scripts/**/*.js',
  'test/mock/**/*.js',
  'test/spec/**/*.js'
],
```

I have also tried using Bower to reinstall ocLacyLoad, as suggested in the aforementioned thread. I was given a choice of versions and selected the first option:

```
Unable to find a suitable version for oclazyload, please choose one:
    1) oclazyload#~0.5.2 which resolved to 0.5.2 and is required by sb-admin
    2) oclazyload#^1.0.9 which resolved to 1.0.9
```

What step am I missing or corrupting here, please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would update oclazyload in bower.json file to version 0.6.0 or higher. Some 0.5.x version introduced this bug and it is solved at 0.6.0 version on.

Current value on bower.json value of the example was 0.5.2 which you used, too.

**References:**

[1] https://github.com/ocombe/ocLazyLoad/issues/122 (*issue in GitHub*)

Comment: I tried updating to 0.6.0. There was no change in output

Comment: did you use `bower uninstall` for the old package? So, that the correct version really comes in use.

Comment: No. I did not take that step. I can't attempt it right now. If the bounty expires before I can try again, and it does work, I will figure out how to get you your points.

Comment: There comes an award period after the bounty expires, another 24h to react.

Comment: Cool, I can definitely find time to test before that time

Comment: Actually, if you can get back to the selection phase, do select !2 instead of 1 and you are ok. You are facing a version conflict and !2 forces the newest to be used always. Look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25915729/unable-to-find-a-suitable-version-for-angular-bower-install and remember the ! before 2 so it greates that resolution!

Answer (score 3):

It looks like this is what you are experiencing:

- [Error in karma testing](https://github.com/ocombe/ocLazyLoad/issues/122)

This should be fixed in `ocLazyLoad` 0.6.0.

Comment: upgraded to 0.6.0. No change